# Poner con formato de Celdas el email que se envía usando CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

Hola quisiera saber como puedo darle un formato de celda al mail con la librería email de codeigniter.

Os dejo el código del controlador que en el cargo el cuerpo del mail.

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cronjob_send_email extends CI_Controller {

    const NOMBRE_FICHERO = "Resumen_Registro";
    const ASUNTO_MAIL = "Resumen de registros";
    const TEXTO_MAIL = "Se han realizado<br> <br> en el hotel {nombreHotel}<br><br> con fecha de hoy.";

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('empleado_model');
        $this->load->model('parametros_model');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->envioMail();
    }

    public function envioMail(){

        $registroBcn = $this->empleado_model->getBarcelona();
        $registroMlg = $this->empleado_model->getMalaga();
        $registroMallorca = $this->empleado_model->getMallorca();

        $textoEnvio = '<html>
            <head>
            <title>Resumen de registros por hotel</title>
            </head>
                <body>
                <h3>Resumen de registros por hotel</h3>
                    <p style="text-align: justify">Se adjunta recuento de registros por Hotel</p>
                <table>
                    <tr style="padding:15px; text-align: center;" >
                        <th>Barcelona</th><span></span>
                        <th>M&aacutelaga</th><span></span>
                        <th>Mallorca</th><span></span>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
                        <td> '.$registroBcn.' </td>
                        <td> '.$registroMlg.' </td>
                        <td> '.$registroMallorca.' </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
//        $textoEnvio = "Adjuntamos recuento de los registros de ayer<br><br>- Barcelona: ".$registroBcn."<br><br>- Málaga";
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'in-v3.mailjet.com',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_user' => '379227d6e1fc18db44209b7e264d8186', // change it to yours
            'smtp_pass' => 'b65e8f015ba7e44ce8d585f812aefb89', // change it to yours
            //'smtp_timeout'=>20,
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
//        $dest = 'jpaulo@stp.es';
//        $from = 'oscarmb83@hotmail.com';
        $dest= $this->parametros_model->get_parametros('destinatario');
        $from=  $this->parametros_model->get_parametros('from');
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($dest);
        $this->email->cc ('htomas@stp.es,arojas@stp.es,omares@stp.es');
//        $copiauno= "arojas@stp.es";
//        $copiados= "omares@stp.es";
//        $copiados= "htomas@stp.es";
//        $this->email->cc ($copiauno.','.$coipados.','.$copiatres);
        $this->email->subject("Recuento de registros diario");
        $this->email->message($textoEnvio);
        //$this->email->send();
        if($this->email->send()){
            echo 'si lo envia '.$from." - ".$dest;
        }
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();





//        /*
//         * Cuando cargamos una librería
//         * es similar a hacer en PHP puro esto:
//         * require_once("libreria.php");
//         * $lib=new Libreria();
//         */
//
//        //Cargamos la librería email
//        $this->load->library('email');
//
//        /*
//         * Configuramos los parámetros para enviar el email,
//         * las siguientes configuraciones es recomendable
//         * hacerlas en el fichero email.php dentro del directorio config,
//         * en este caso para hacer un ejemplo rápido lo hacemos
//         * en el propio controlador
//         */
//
//        //Indicamos el protocolo a utilizar
//        $config['protocol'] = 'imap';
//
//        //El servidor de correo que utilizaremos
//        $config["smtp_host"] = 'imap.gmail.com';
//
//        //Nuestro usuario
//        $config["smtp_user"] = 'joaoarias2699@gmail.com';
//
//        //Nuestra contraseña
//        $config["smtp_pass"] = 'joaoymichu2';
//
//        //El puerto que utilizará el servidor smtp
//        $config["smtp_port"] = '993';
//
//        //El juego de caracteres a utilizar
//        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
//
//        //Permitimos que se puedan cortar palabras
//        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
//
//        //El email debe ser valido
//        $config['validate'] = true;
//
//
//        //Establecemos esta configuración
//        $this->email->initialize($config);
//
//        //Ponemos la dirección de correo que enviará el email y un nombre
//        $this->email->from('joaoarias2699@gmail.com', 'Oscar');
//
//        /*
//         * Ponemos el o los destinatarios para los que va el email
//         * en este caso al ser un formulario de contacto te lo enviarás a ti
//         * mismo
//         */
//        $this->email->to('oscarmb83@gmail.com');
//        $this->email->cc ( 'htomas@stp.es' );
//
//        //Definimos el asunto del mensaje
//        $this->email->subject("Mi asunto");
//
//        //Definimos el mensaje a enviar
//        $this->email->message("Mi mensaje");
//
//        //Enviamos el email y si se produce bien o mal que avise con una flasdata
//        if($this->email->send()){
//            echo 'si';
//        }else{
//            echo 'no';
//        }

        //redirect(base_url("contacto"));
    }



//    public function envioMail(){
//        $this->email->from ( 'oscarmb83@gmail.com ' ,  'Joao' );
//        $this->email->to ( ' omares@stp.es ' );
//        $this->email->cc ( 'htomas@stp.es' );
//        $this->email->bcc ( '' );
//
//        $this->email->subject ( 'Test de correo electrónico' );
//        $this->email->message ( 'Probando la clase de correo electrónico' );
//
//        $this->email->send ();
//    }

}
```

Asi se ve actual mente el mail, lo que quisiera es poner los bordes de celdas, lo he intentando ponerle en el la propia etiqueta el style pero no me lo cambia

Agradecería vuestra ayuda .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas agregar un estilo `css` después de la etiqueta `title`:

```
<title>Resumen de registros por hotel</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Un caso interesante es que el atributo `border` no es compatible con `html5`, si así lo has declarado, necesitas usar `css`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, con ese ejemplo se solucionó mi problema.